# How to Merge Some Column from Row into another Column

Tags: sql

I am getting some set of rows from SQL query.
Which is mentioned below. For example:

```
UnitName    Requisition_No  14.11   14.141  14.144
A              1303a        1000    NULL    NULL
A              1303a        NULL    2000    NULL
A              1303a        NULL    NULL    3000
```

But the output should be like this:

```
UnitName    Requisition_No  14.11   14.141  14.144
A                1303a      1000    2000    3000
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the columns meant to be unique and use aggregate functions like `max()` to get the values not being `null`

```
select UnitName, Requisition_No, max(14.11), max(14.141), max(14.144)
from your_table
group by UnitName, Requisition_No
```

Comment: Thank you sir.it help me lot